# How to achieve better compression ratio in 7z format with HEVC files

Tags: compression

I use an open source compression software named Peazip running on a Intel Core i5-8250U @1.6 GHz processor. However, I have tried compressing files to 7z many times but the compression ratio is hardly less than 98%. Is it because of the processor or something else? Anyone please let me know how do I get a better compression ratio and do recommend any other alternative software that can achieve it. I have tried various compression softwares (even the official one), but the result hardly varies. If it some other issue let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Compression programs work by seeking out redundancy and repeated data.

Video compression is a many layered approach of removing repeated sequences and redundant data to reduce the size of a video stream from a massive amount of data to as small a size as possible.

HEVC is a very efficient compression algorithm that can achieve (up to) [1000:1 compression ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding), at the cost of loss of quality.

The reason you cannot compress it further is because it is already very well compressed.

You are unlikely to find any program that will achieve significant compression.